# Cordova move "mouse"/"last touched" position

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

In my Cordova app use a `:hover` pseudo-class to give something styling, when the user clicks it, i want to remove that `:hover` so i have to move the spot of last touch, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` is not available mobile devices. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Cordova apps are html pages, so Im using the :hover as a menu opener trick. So rather then overlay a modal to detect blur click to close menu, when user touches anywhere else it moves that invisible mouse so that element is no longer hovered so it closes. It works pretty good. Just i need to move that invisible mouse some how.

Comment: Touch is not designed that way. You can see examples in fastclick.js